# Basic UI components not found in NativeScript for Angular

Tags: android, ios, angular, nativescript

I am working on NativeScript with Angular 2, but I cannot find some very simple things.

For e.g.

- A date input field with a date picker on tap.
- A select dropdown with options.
- A file/image input field that can browse phone storage or take camera photo.

I cannot find these basic widgets while some other similar widgets do exist, like TextInput, TextView, etc.

If any one knows how to work with this, please help.

Comment: You realize that there are  hundreds of frameworks that don't include anything nearly that complicated in them, right?  And that you can always include libraries built on top of the framework.  If you have very specific wants like that, time to start writing them.  You are a programmer after all.

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for taking the time to reply, but what you are calling specific wants are not very specific, they are general. A simple date input, or select dropdown is the least that a framework should have. I was hoping to get an answer from a NativeScript expert. But thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: No, they aren't general. They're very specific, and few to go frameworks will have them.

Comment: Sorry @GabeSechan I dis-agree with you on this. They are as general as a text field input or a number input. Anything that is used commonly is general.

Comment: You have unreasonable expectations. Especially the 3rd, native android itself doesn't have that

Comment: Yes I agree on the 3rd one, but the first 2 are very general. Thanks

Comment: Actually native android doesn't have a number input either.

Comment: It does when you provide the inputType https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style

Comment: That isn't what I'd consider a number picker. It's a text field. And it working depends on the keyboard app having a number node. A number picker doesn't allow non numerical, which input mode numeric doesn't do, and provides increment and decrement uis

Comment: :D but its the same as what I mentioned in number 1 with date input. A general thing available in all general devices. Moreover, a framework built on top of android has to offer more than what is available in the base. Anyway, the answer to my question was a simple "No, its not available", not a useless argument. Cheers!

Comment: Actually no it doesn't need to provide more-  its main purpose is cross platform (which usually provides *less*) and allowing it to be used in Javascript instead of Java/kotlin, which provides value if you don't want to learn a new language.  Its  EXTREMELY common for those kind of frameworks to offer fewer features.Honestly 2 is the only one I'd expect to see supported as part of a base framework.

Comment: Actually it is available in the framework. I am posting the details as an answer below. Thanks @GabeSechan for the motivation. You actually forced me to look harder :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NativeScript framework actually has many widgets in their market as plugins. They are not available by default but they can be found in the market:

https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/

Here is one for the datepicker:

https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-datetimepicker
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-datetimepicker

It actually works exactly as asked in the question. It can be used to show a date field, and when clicked, it shows the date picker. The urls above also show screenshots of iOS and Android.

Here is a picker field that works like the Select Dropdown:

https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-picker